# boost::hana::map as a data member

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

I am currently learning `boost::hana` for a personal project.

In the following code snippet I created a `boost::hana::map` having a `type_c<T>` as key and an instance of `Foo<T>` as value.

It works but I would really like to use the `my_map` variable as a **class member** and it is not possible to use `auto` qualifier in member declarations. Moreover it would be great if I could have the possibility to pass the `types` tuple in some way (as a template parameter or as a constructor parameter).

Do you have any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/hana.hpp"
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace boost;

template<typename T>
class Foo {
    T t;    
public:    
    void print() { std::cout <<typeid(T).name() << t; }    
};

int main() {
    auto types = hana::tuple_t<float, int, std::string>;

    auto my_map = boost::hana::unpack(types, [](auto ...t) {
        return boost::hana::make_map(boost::hana::make_pair(t, Foo<typename decltype(t)::type>()) ...);
    });

    my_map[hana::type_c<int>].print();
}
```

Comment: Typedefs and `decltype`?

Comment: Of course, I tried something link 

`auto my_map = [] (auto types) {
return boost::hana::unpack(types, [](auto ...t) {
        return boost::hana::make_map(boost::hana::make_pair(t, Foo<typename decltype(t)::type>()) ...);
    });

class MapContainer {
  using MapType = decltype(my_map(types));
MapType map;
/*.. etc ... */
}
`
but I cannot find a way to pass `types` tuple to the class, without making it global (I think I have to pass it using a template...) can you suggest something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185951/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-the-map-type

Comment: Are you saying that you want `my_map` to be a **member** of a class?

Comment: Yes. I was quite confused with the strange wording too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that lambdas cannot be used in un-evaluated context (`decltype`).

Of course, since c++14 we can just use deduced return types on any free function:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename... T>
    static inline auto make_foo_map() {
        return boost::hana::unpack(hana::tuple_t<T...>, [](auto... t) {
                return boost::hana::make_map(boost::hana::make_pair(t, Foo<typename decltype(t)::type>())...);
            });
    }
}

template <typename... T>
using FooMap = decltype(detail::make_foo_map<T...>());
```

Now it's simply:

```
FooMap<float, int, std::string> my_map;
```

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5111b3a8b7a0c76e)</kbd>**

```
#include "boost/hana.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace boost;

template <typename T> class Foo {
    T t;

  public:
    void print() { std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "t\n"; }
};

namespace detail {
    template <typename... T>
    static inline auto make_foo_map() {
        return boost::hana::unpack(hana::tuple_t<T...>, [](auto... t) {
                return boost::hana::make_map(boost::hana::make_pair(t, Foo<typename decltype(t)::type>())...);
            });
    }
}

template <typename... T>
using FooMap = decltype(detail::make_foo_map<T...>());

int main() {
    FooMap<float, int, std::string> my_map;

    my_map[hana::type_c<int>].print();
    my_map[hana::type_c<float>].print();
    my_map[hana::type_c<std::string>].print();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for.

Comment: I managed the code to pass the decltype of the `hana::tuple` as template argument and store an `hana::tuple` instance as class member (initializing it in the construcor). Hana is really powerful. Can you suggest me a book to learn C++14 metaprogramming?